# SharePoint 2013 Custom Ribbon Action inside Custom Group

Tags: javascript, ribbon, xml

I am trying to make a Custom Ribbon Action within Visual Studio. This works perfectly fine but I would like the Custom Action to reside in a custom group. I've seen lots of helpful(ish) threads/videos out there and nothing is working. I keep getting errors at runtime despite following the instructions to the T. I have stepped back to the Custom Ribbon Action at it's bare bones and am looking for any helpful input as to how I can move the Custom Action into it's own group.

**UPDATE:** I tried doing this on a SharePoint 2013 on prem instance and everything works perfectly fine. Is this some type of limitation with SharePoint Online? Is there a workaround?

Here is the Elements.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="458f7307-01fd-4fa8-9da3-e47e8e719ab5.RibbonCustomAction1"
                RegistrationType="List"
                RegistrationId="115"
                Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
                Sequence="10001"
                Title="Invoke &apos;RibbonCustomAction1&apos; action">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <!-- 
      Update the UI definitions below with the controls and the command actions
      that you want to enable for the custom action.
      -->
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Library.Settings.Controls._children">
          <Button Id="Ribbon.Library.Settings.RibbonCustomAction1Button"
                  Alt="Request RibbonCustomAction1"
                  Sequence="100"
                  Command="Invoke_RibbonCustomAction1ButtonRequest"
                  LabelText="Request RibbonCustomAction1"
                  TemplateAlias="o1"
                  Image32by32="_layouts/15/images/placeholder32x32.png"
                  Image16by16="_layouts/15/images/placeholder16x16.png" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_RibbonCustomAction1ButtonRequest"
                          CommandAction="~appWebUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPListItemId={SelectedItemId}&amp;SPListId={SelectedListId}"/>
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension >
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Do I need to create the custom group in an external file or do I use what's already there in Elements.XML and modify it?

Comment: Are you deploying it to SharePoint online using an App or Sandbox solution? I don't see anything unusual in the XML here. Also, what permission does user (who deploys it) have?

Comment: I'm deploying it to SharePoint Online (SharePoint App). I have the highest permissions to the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with pure SharePoint Online/O365.